# Connection reset by remote server

Tags: ssh, freebsd

I am trying to ssh remote server from my local server. But whenever I run ssh command:

```
ssh root@x.x.x.x
```

I get error:

> Connection closed by x.x.x.x

I changed the ownership of the `/etc/` directory and now I cannot log in with any user that was configured before.

Output of `ssh -v -v -v -v root@x.x.x.x` is:

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2     FreeBSD-20160310
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2 FreeBSD-20160310 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to x.x.x.x:22 as 'user11'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file    /c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file   /c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 2 keys from x.x.x.x
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-    v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-  cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-  sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-  nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-  sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192- ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256  SHA256:GKq038GQBLs90z1p/mR0X7wFHx+b/lflv8mE21N1+0E
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file  /c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 2 keys from x.x.x.x
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from x.x.x.x
debug1: Host 'x.x.x.x' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_rsa (0x60006bde0),
debug2: key: /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by x.x.x.x
```

I have loaded content of my `id_rsa.pub` in `authorized_keys`.

I cannot ssh login. I have researched the matter and tried the suggestions but I have no access as I cannot login. I cannot modify the `/etc/` file as well as access is not granted.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: The content of your `id_rsa.pub` should be in `authorized_keys` on the server, not in `known_hosts`.

Comment: thank you for your valued response, thanks for pointing it out I made an error on typing it is in the authorized_keys on the server

Comment: What is the sshd configuration on the remote server? Have you tried logging in as an ordinary (non-root) user?

Comment: Hi @RedGrittyBrick yes I have tried to login with a non-root user but I am still getting the connection closed error. For the configuration I am not sure as I dont have access but I think its config5

Comment: On which machine did you change the ownership of `/etc`? local or remote?

Comment: Hi @RedGrittyBrick I made the changes on the remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I changed the ownership of the /etc/ directory**

Messing around with ownership and permissions of system directories is usually inadvisable - unless you are an operating system developer who understands *all* the ramifications.

> **and now I cannot log in**

At startup sshd reads various files from /etc/ssh/, but it probably caches a lot of this and as Dave Thompson pointed out in a comment, your client trace has suggests the server had no issues reading it's key-pair or other SSH configuration files.

It is possible that sshd is now unable to read something else in /etc/ or considers it insecure. I'd guess the latter. But it is a guess.

The server logs probably contain some message that would help understand what it happening, but of course those are now inaccessible.

If so, the only way to fix this might be to travel to the remote server and use a console to login. Failing that, boot a rescue CD / USB-drive.

Comment: The client trace shows receiving a host key which matches client's known_hosts, so server sshd is not unhappy with his own key(s), and KEX used ECDH so it didn't need the moduli file. But concur OP needs to look at server logs -- which without remote access means going to it.

Comment: Thanks  a lot RedGrittyBrick and @dave_thompson, I guess I have no other option than to boot the server. Thanks for the assistance I really appreciate it.